# nginx - upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, nginx-config

I have a e-commerce project written in python and flask framework, I keep shopping cart information on session, when I try add product to session, nginx gives this error:

> upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mysite.com, request: "POST /add_to_cart HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/path/uwsgi.sock:", host: "mysite.com"

This occurs when I have a lot of information in session,

I tried adding `fastcgi` and `proxy_buffer` parameters, but still not working, here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  mysite.com;

  ssl_certificate       /path/nginx.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key   /path/nginx.key;

  include              /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam          /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  access_log      /path/access.log main;

  fastcgi_buffers  16 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

  proxy_buffering             on;
  proxy_buffer_size         128k;
  proxy_buffers           4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

  location /static/ {
    alias         /path/web/static/;
    access_log    off;
    index         index.html index.htm;
  }

  location / {
    try_files       $uri @uwsgi;
    root            /path/www/;
    index           index.html index.htm;    
  }

  location @uwsgi {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass  unix:/path/web/uwsgi.sock;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code related to the session and how the sessions systen is set up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're capable of reconstructing exact `POST` request via `curl` or otherwise measure the actual header size, you can specify the proper size for `uwsgi_buffer_size` (the directive that is related in your case).

Here's my [post](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx) that has some insight into a similiar directive, `proxy_buffer_size`. There are many `*_buffer_size` directives, each "proxy"-like NGINX module has one (fastcgi, proxy, uwsgi), but how you approach their tuning (and how they essentially work) is the same.

You can try, without measurement, by placing directly in `server` block:

```
uwsgi_buffer_size 16k; 
uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 24k;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to use uwsgi buffer parameter, I didn't know that there is such parameter ;), thanks

Comment: Thanks Danila your answer was very helpful and solved my problem! I had already increased nginx proxy buffer size and fastcgi but needed to increase uwsgi size as well

Comment: Thank you, Danila! it solved my problem too! I put nginx proxy buffer size and fastcgi but it wasn't working and I didn't know I should increase uwsgi size.